# Raspberry won't boot (even after replacing sd and power supply)

Tags: boot, boot-issues, troubleshooting

I was working on my raspberry over ssh, and then I lost connection with it.

So then I saw that when it boots the red lights turns on while the green light doesn't light on and there is no display.

Firstly I thought it was a power problem so I switch multiple power supplies and it didn't help.

Then I took a new sd flashed it with the newest raspian version and it also didn't help.

Then I took a USB drive flashed it with raspian and still it didn't fix the problem.

I have searched throughout the web and I didn't find other advice other than change power supply/sd.

What can cause the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you worked through https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151 ?

Comment: Does any part of your RPi get too hot to touch very quickly? Can you measure 3.3V between pin#1 and the metal case of the USB sockets? Have you shorted pin#1 to pin#2 (or pin#4)? Your fix may cost £35.

Comment: No part is getting really hot, and I cannot massure the voltage because I don't have DMM in nearby